# How to add an additional option to an option form which is filled with a db query

Tags: php, echo, html-select

How can I add an extra `<option>` with a value of `all` to:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("tnews2") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT name,id,path FROM categories ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT  0,6";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()."[".$query."]");
?>

<select name="categories">
<?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['path']."'>'".$row['name']."'</option>";
}
?>        
</select>
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions

*Edit*

```
echo "<th>Tierart";
$query = $pdo->query("select sp_term from species");
//Abfrage der Tabelle Tierart
echo '<select name="sp_term">';
while ($sql_sp_term = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="all">all</option>';
    echo '<option value="'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'">'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: You could add another `<option value="all">All</option>` after the `while` in the `select` right? Is that not something you're willing to do?

Comment: yes, I already tried that, but it gives all out every second line:

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the HTML structure when you do this?

Comment: unfortunatelly I cant edit my question                             echo "<th>Tierart";
 $query = $pdo->query("select sp_term from species"); //Abfrage der Tabelle Tierart
 echo '<select name="sp_term">'; 
 while ($sql_sp_term = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
 echo '<option value="all">all</option>';
 echo '<option value="'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'">'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'</option>'; 
}
echo '</select>';

Comment: Your `echo '<option value="all">all</option>';` is inside the `while()` loop, take it out of the loop immediately after the `<select name="sp_term">` line. That way you'll only have show up once.

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped, i've posted the same as an answer which you could accept as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're populating the values of `option` in a `select` tag section with a database query doing something as follows would do the trick.

```
echo '<select name="sp_term">';
while ($sql_sp_term = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'">'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

However, when you want to add an additional item like `All` as an option, place an explicit `option` value before the while/after the while depending on your requirement and you'll have the `select > option` with the new `All` option added to the options from the database.

```
echo '<select name="sp_term">';
echo '<option value="all">all</option>';
while ($sql_sp_term = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'">'.$sql_sp_term['sp_term'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```